# Linux: how to implement warning the user when they start typing with non-English keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Does anyone know how to implement a momentary floating notification that the user (me) is not using English keyboard layout when they press a letter, numeral or other layout-dependant key (so no need for notification when pressing Super, Ctrl, Alt, Tab etc). That notification shouldn't steal focus, but work something like `key-mon` or `screenkey` in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raw0OtUej6k

It can either show the letter or just the language in use, e.g. "CZ". It should disappear after about a second after its been shown and not reappear unless I stop typing for a long period of time (e.g. 10 seconds) and then start typing again.

It would also be good if the solution could implement not only a visual notification but also a sound. It would be great if the solution was compatible with i3 window manager. These are desirable, but not necessary.

I, personally, need this because I often find myself in non-English keyboard layout while trying to control applications which have English controls. An example would be ranger file manager.

What I've tried so far are the aforementioned `key-mon` and `screenkey`. However, they don't have any suitable such option, and I don't know what else to try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: It seems like you're asking others to write a solution for you? What have you already tried? What is your specific question? Are you merely asking if and how that could be done?

Comment: Yes, @slhck, I'm asking if and how that could be done. What I did so far was to install `key-mon` and `screenkey` and tried to configure them to do that (react only to non-English keystrokes), but they don't have such options. So now I don't even know where else to start looking. Yes, @JamoBox, it's not a question, I'll delete the question mark. Initially I wrote a grammatically correct question, but it was too long, so I discarded the "How to make Linux" part and it became awkward.

Comment: I didn't mean it wasn't a question from a grammatical context, rather that your post as a whole does not ask anything. It simply states your intent and makes no mention of your attempts or issues you have come across, making it seem as if you just want someone to do it all for you.

Comment: @JamoBox, I've edited the question according to your words. (As you can see from my reputation count, I'm a new stackexchange user, so I'm making mistakes, although these mistakes are stupid)